# How to use await a method until retrofit response is done and execute next code in android java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, async-await, retrofit

I want to wait CheckDataBaseWithRFID this method complete .
Already tried with, extends AsyncTask<>  same result

***Output getting like this-->***

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: AddReadTag START:

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: AddReadTag: Assigned ? = false

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: AddReadTag END

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: onResponse: Location ---  X121212121

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: onResponse:  currentTagAlreadyAssign = true    ---  X121212121

***Output need to be like this -->***

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: AddReadTag START:

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: onResponse: Location ---  X121212121

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: onResponse:  currentTagAlreadyAssign = true    ---  X121212121

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: AddReadTag: Assigned ? = true

E/LocationTagAssignFragment: AddReadTag END

```
 public void AddReadTag(String EPC, String Rssi) {

        RfidModel rfidModel = new RfidModel();
        if (!CheckAlreadyReadTags(EPC, Rssi)) {
            rfidModel.setRfid(EPC);
            rfidModel.setCount(1);
            rfidModel.setRssi(Rssi);
            Log.e(TAG, "AddReadTag START: ");

           // await this CheckDataBaseWithRFID methode until complete 

            boolean isAssigned = CheckDataBaseWithRFID(EPC.trim());
 
            rfidModel.setAlreadyAssigned(isAssigned);
            Log.e(TAG, "AddReadTag: Assigned ? = " + isAssigned);
            Log.e(TAG, "AddReadTag END");

            rfidLocationList.add(rfidModel);
            updateRecyclerList();
        }
  }
 
 public boolean CheckDataBaseWithRFID(String RFIDTag) {
        currentTagAlreadyAssign = false;
        Call<RFIDCodeIsExistsModel> isExistsRFID = ApiClient.AssetService().checkRFIDCodeIsExists(RFIDTag);
        isExistsRFID.enqueue(new Callback<RFIDCodeIsExistsModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RFIDCodeIsExistsModel> call, Response<RFIDCodeIsExistsModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getType() + " ---  " + RFIDTag);
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:  currentTagAlreadyAssign = true   " + " ---  " + RFIDTag);`enter code here`
                    currentTagAlreadyAssign = true; 
                } else { 
                    Log.e(TAG, "No items assign with this Tag");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RFIDCodeIsExistsModel> call, Throwable t) {
              
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("Connection Failed", "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
        return currentTagAlreadyAssign;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the code you want to wait for in the onResponse/onFailure functions.  This is a callback, it doesn't return a promise.